# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, huawei-mobile-services

I create app that uses Huawei SDK written in Objc with updated docs in Oct 2017. But when I add framework to project, this shows me stange [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxlkF.jpg). I have stack on this problem couple days, I have tried everything from similar problems, but nothing helped for me.
Framework added correctly(header file, link binary with libraries) autocomplition works well and shows the methods when trying to use SDK.

Already tried: change/edit/update

1. Valid architecture: arm, armv, armv7, armv7s, i386, x64_86
2. Clean Derived date and achieves
3. Restart OS
4. Change swift version: Shows another error
5. Checked ObjC bridging header
6. Pod update/install
7. Framework search path

**SOLUTION:**

Launch on real device=)

Comment: You're compiling for the simulator. But does it work on a real device?

Comment: Yeah, app runs successfully in real Device. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your HWMobileSDK.framework is not a fat framework.  You'll either need to find a fat framework, or a second build of the framework that's compiled for the simulator (x86_64).  I couldn't find any reference to that framework online, so it looks like it's not publicly available. If you got this from Huawei directly, you should ask the person you're in contact with there.  Either they don't provide a version of the library for the simulator and you'll need to develop using a device only, or you need another version of the library.

Comment: thanks, a lot). I have written to Huawei Support Center. The problem was in using the app in Simulator, I have launch in real device, and runs successfully.